# Cannot add custom cursor to sortable (jQuery, CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, cursor, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to customize the cursor for sortable objects, but no success. However, I am able to change the cursor to 'move'. In css I have cursor: url(../images/cursor.png) and the browser successfully finds the image. For all other elements I was able to add image to cursor, but not for sortable. Below is my code for sortable. Basically I have elements in two columns and I can drag elements from one column to another and vice versa.

```js
var categoriesCombArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6, 7, 8];
var category1Arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];


$(function() {
    $("#column1, #column2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column", 
    });
});



for (i = 0; i < categoriesCombArr.length; i++) {
        if (i < category1Arr.length) {
            $("#column1").append("<div class='choice'><div class = 'image' id = 'choice" + i + "'></div><div class = 'imageDescription'><p>" + categoriesCombArr[i] + "</p></div> </div>");
        } else {
            $("#column2").append("<div class='choice'><div class = 'image' id = 'choice" + i + "'></div><div class = 'imageDescription'><p>" + categoriesCombArr[i] + "</p></div> </div>");
        }

    }
```

```css
.choice {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: SansPro-Regular;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(181, 152, 113);
    margin-top: 7px;
    cursor: url(../images/cursor.png) !important;
}

.choice:hover {
    background-color: #bd7737;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(43, 27, 0, 0.34);
    cursor: url(../images/cursor.png) !important;
}




#column1{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    /*! left: 200px; */
    text-align: center;
    
    
    top: 19px;
    overflow: scroll;
    left: 35px;
}

#column2{
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;   
    /*! right: 200px; */
    
    text-align: center;
    left: -36px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class = "columnsCollection"> 
 <!-- column1 -->
 <div>
    <div id='column1' class = "column">
    <!-- ALL CONTENT appears here -->
    </div>
 </div>
        <!-- column1 ends here -->

 <div class="progress-bar"></div>

 <!-- column2 -->
 <div>
    <div id = 'column2' class= 'column'>
    <!-- ALL CONTENT appears here -->
    </div>
 </div>
 <!-- column2 ends here -->

</div>
<!-- columnsCollection ends heres -->
```

Comment: Try using `cursor: url(../images/cursor.png)!important;` also try to post html code here

Comment: I think you need to show some more of your code. What does the HTML look like? What CSS selector are you using, etc.

Comment: @AtalKishore already tried, but didn't work

Comment: @3ocene added all my code. Can you take a look please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ is a useful site. It allows you to group all your code in one example that can be run. That way, lazy people like me are more likely to help. Or you can do what Albert Font did in his answer and use a snippet.

Comment: As for answering your question, I'm not sure what the issue is. Hopefully one of the CSS gods on this site will come around if you haven't got a helpful answer yet. It looks like Albert Font has solved the problem [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39972281/4060711).

Comment: @3ocene added the code to jsfiddle.net, so that you can see what I am trying to do.

Comment: @3ocene anyways thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled accross the answer while looking at [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/). It looks like when you use a custom cursor from a URL, you also need to specify a backup cursor from the built in ones, like so:

```
cursor: url(../images/cursor.png), move;
```

This is presumably so that the browser knows what to use if the image is unavailable.

You can also specify a list of cursors and the browser will use the first one that works:

```
cursor: url(unavailable.png), url(../images/cursor.png), move;
```

Comment: damn, dude, you are a man! Thanks a lot! adding 'move' did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Can you take at this code, maybe it helps you.

Regards,

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      cancel: ".noSortable"
    });
   
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table {
 font-size: 1em;
}

.ui-draggable, .ui-droppable {
 background-position: top;
}

#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px;cursor:move; }
#sortable li.noSortable{cursor:no-drop;}
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default noSortable">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default noSortable">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default noSortable">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: When you answer a question, try to add more info about what you're doing and why. Dumping code in an answer is almost (but not quite) as bad as dumping code in a question imo.